# React component that's rendered dynamically does not rerender on parent state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that I want to run through a non react animation library before render.  This has prevented me from going the standard route of just using the standard hide/show logic.  I initially tried to use ReactDOM.createPortal but that didn't render the component at all.  Using ReactDOM.render, I've gotten the element to render correctly upon completion of the animation and I'm able to successfully propagate changes up to the "parent" state but the state change doesn't propagate back down to the "child".  Here's my code:

Html

```
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="childPlaceholder"></div>
```

Javascript

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function App() {
  const [data, updateData] = useState(0)
  function add(val) {
    console.log("add");
    updateData(val);
  }
  function renderSubpage() {


    let $el = document.getElementById("childPlaceholder");
    // NonReactAnimationLibrary.ShowContainer($el);
    ReactDOM.render(<Child number={data} add={add} />, $el);
    // ReactDOM.createPortal(<Child number={data} add={add} />, $el);

  }
  return ( <>
    <button onClick={renderSubpage}>
      add child
    </button>
    <div> data: {data}</div>
</>
  );
}
function Child(props) {
  return <>
  <button onClick={()=>{props.add(props.number + 1)}}>add number</button>
    <div>child {props.number}</div>
  </>
}

export default App;
```

Is it possible to do this in react?

**Update 1:**

So I've updated the code per Olivers response, it renders correctly using the portal but the child components still don't rerender on state changes in the Parent Component

```
const root = document.getElementById("root");
const childRoot = document.getElementById("childPlaceholder");

function Child(args) {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(<>
   <div>child:  {args.number}</div>
   <button onClick={()=>{args.add(args.number+1)}}>Increment base number</button>
  </>, childRoot);
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { data: 0, number:0 };
  }
  
 
  add = (val)=> {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      number: val
    });
  }
  addChild = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({data: prevState.data + 1}));
  }
  render() {
    const children = Array(this.state.data)
      .fill()
      .map((_, i) => <Child key={i} number={0} add={this.add}/>);
  
    return ( 
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.addChild}>
          add child
        </button>
        <div> data: {this.state.data}</div>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, root);
```

Update 2:

The culprit was found.  Changed

```
      number={0}
```

to

```
      number={this.state.number}
```

and it works

Comment: What do you mean by: "propagate back down to the "child"?

Comment: the {props.number} value in the Child component doesn't update while the {data} value  in the App component does

Comment: this is a perfect use case for `ReactDOM.createPortal`, I don't understand why it didn't work for you, maybe you didn't use it correctly.

Comment: The only difference was that I called ReactDOM.createPortal instead of ReactDOM.render with the same arguments.  Is that the right way to use it?  I added how I tried to use it to the post

Comment: ReactDOM.createPortal must be used inisde render method, you can look at the documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Comment: Looking at the doc, it looks like you need to put the portal component inside of the Parent's return but when I do that, it just renders immediately

Comment: you don't need `...this.state`, you can simply write `this.setState({number: val});`. As I said in my answer you can perfectly use function component with hooks. I didn't use it because Stackoverflow doesn't support latest version of react when writting code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.createPortal` must be used inside the render method (I used a class component because I cannot use hooks in the SO example, you can of course use a functional component).

You can use it in the `App` component like below or in the `Child` component :

```js
const root = document.getElementById("root");
const childRoot = document.getElementById("childPlaceholder");

function Child({number}) {
  return <div>child {number}</div>;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { data: 0 };
  }
  
  addChild = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({data: prevState.data + 1}));
  }
  
  render() {
    const children = Array(this.state.data)
      .fill()
      .map((_, i) => <Child key={i} number={i} />);
  
    return ( 
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.addChild}>add child</button>
        <div> data: {this.state.data}</div>
        {ReactDOM.createPortal(children, childRoot)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<div id="childPlaceholder"></div>
```

Comment: I was able to get the rendering part working correctly but when I put the on click function to increment the parent state number back in, it still doesn't cause the child components to rerender

Comment: I've added my updated code to the original post

Comment: its apparently because I'm dumb and I passed in a 0 instead of the number property in the parents state.  Thank you so much!!!